# Sum of Digit Permutations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations, puzzle

The question simply states "Let a secret three digit number be $cba$. If the sum of $cab + bac + bca + abc + acb = 2536$, what is $cba$?" I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of all six numbers is 222c + 222b + 222a 
If we omit cba = (100c + 10b + a), what is left is 
N = 122c + 212b + 221a which is what we are given.

Observing 221 = 13*17, 
we have N = 5c + 4b mod 13 and N = 3c + 8b mod 17 
(We could have used factors of 122 or 212, but 2*61 and 
2*2*53 are not nearly so convenient as 13 and 17.)

For N = 2536, we have N mod 13 = 1 and N mod 17 = 3 
So we have 1 = 5c + 4b mod 13 and 3 = 3c + 8b mod 17

Since b and c are digits in range 0-9, we can try each value of b for 0 through 9 
and complete the table below as follows:

- Compute 4 x b and 4 x b mod 13.
- Subtract that from 1 to (5c mod 13).
- Then find a suitable value for c which satisfies that.
- For example 5c = 1 mod 13 -> 5c = 40, c = 8.
- Then compute 3c+8b (mod 17) and find the one which equals 3.

b   4b  4b mod 13   5c mod 13   5c  c   (3c + 8b) mod 17
0   0   0   1   40  8   7
1   4   4   10  10  2   14
2   8   8   6   45  9   9
3   12  12  2   15  3   16
4   16  3   11  50  10  11
5   20  7   7   20  4   1
6   24  11  3   55  11  13
7   28  2   12  25  5   3
8   32  6   8   60  12  15
9   36  10  4   30  6   5

Examining the table, we see it is the row where b = 7 and c = 5. 
So we know that the original number was 57a. 
To determine a, we take 2536 - 122*5 - 212*7 = 2536 - 610 - 1484 = 442 
Dividing by 221, we get a = 2, so the original number was 572. 
We can verify that 527+725+752+257+275 = 2536.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$222(a+b+c)-(cba)=2536$$

Try with multiples of $222$ nearing $2536$

---

OR

$$\iff220a+202b+22c=2536\iff202b+22c=2536-220a$$

Comment: Where did the 222 come from?

Comment: @anonymous, We have $abc+acb+bca+bac+cab+cba-cba=2536$

Comment: Oh ok that makes so much more sense now i understand :) thanks for the help...greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since $cab + bac + bca + abc + acb = 2536$ and we know that the sum of digits are

Ones digit: $2c + 2b + a$

Tens digit: $2c + b + 2a$

Hundreds digit: $c + 2b + 2a$

So now we have

$\quad \quad 100(c + 2b + 2a) + 10(2c + b + 2a) + (2c + 2b + a) = 2536$

$\implies 122c + 212b + 221a = 2536$

Answer (score 0):

$cab+bac+bca+abc+acb$ $+cba$ $=2536$+$cba$

$\displaystyle\Rightarrow \frac{2536+(100c+10b+a)}{111}=(2a+2b+2c)$

$\displaystyle 14 \le (a+b+c)\le 20$

and $\quad cba=222(a+b+c)-2536$

Checking with $\quad (a+b+c)=14\quad $ found $\quad cba=572$